# Group by one field with all values from the other

Tags: sql, oracle, select

If I have a table that has two fields (client, service) and lets say the table look like this:

```
client | Service
  1    |   A
  1    |   B
  1    |   C
  2    |   A
  2    |   D
```

I want to do a select statement that I can have all services from each client so the result would look like this

```
client  | Service
  1     | A, B, C
  2     | A, D
```

Is it possible in SQL? I am using oracle 10g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg` in this case -

```
select client, 
       listagg(service, ', ') within group (order by service) as service 
from the_table 
group by client;
```

`listagg` can be used either as an aggregate function or as an analytic function.
Read more from here- [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm)